# How to set panTo auto zoom on click of a marker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map on which I am plotting some random co-ordinates, co-ordinates being fed into a data table and is working fine

But now since I have been trying to set a `panTo` zoom feature on my map so that when any one of the markers are clicked then the map canvas slowly zooms in to the marker.
I am not able to set it properly.

So, How can I make this work? Any suggestions/answers are much appreciated..Thanks in advance.

My GPSLib Class:

```
public static class GPSLib
{
    public static String PlotGPSPoints(DataTable tblPoints)
    {
        try
        {
            String Locations = "";
            String sJScript = "";
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow r in tblPoints.Rows)
            {
                // bypass empty rows 
                if (r["latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                    continue;

                string Latitude = r["latitude"].ToString();
                string Longitude = r["longitude"].ToString();

                // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record 
                Locations += Environment.NewLine + @"
                path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(" + Latitude + ", " + Longitude + @"));

                var marker" + i.ToString() + @" = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + Latitude + ", " + Longitude + @"),
                    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
                    map: map
                });";
                i++;
            }

            // construct the final script
            // var cmloc = new google.maps.LatLng(33.779005, -118.178985);

            // map.panTo(curmarker.position); //zooming on current marker's posn.
            // map.panTo(myOptions.getPosition());
            sJScript = @"<script type='text/javascript'>

            var poly;
            var map;

            function initialize() {
                var cmloc = new google.maps.LatLng(28.483243, 77.107624);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 19,
                    center: cmloc,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);


                var polyOptions = {
                    strokeColor: 'blue',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 3
                }
                poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
                poly.setMap(map);

                var path = poly.getPath();

               " + Locations + @"

                    }
                </script>";
            return sJScript;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the aspx page's `onLoad()` method which creates a data table containing co-ordinates:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Latitude"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Longitude"));

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Latitude"] = 28.483109;
            row["Longitude"] = 77.107756;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Latitude"] = 28.483243;
            row["Longitude"] = 77.107624;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Latitude"] = 28.483293;
            row["Longitude"] = 77.107579;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Latitude"] = 28.483359;
            row["Longitude"] = 77.107536;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Latitude"] = 28.483559;
            row["Longitude"] = 77.107273;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            //row = dt.NewRow();
            //row["Latitude"] = 28.4804;
            //row["Longitude"] = 77.1251;
            //dt.Rows.Add(row);

            js.Text = GPSLib.PlotGPSPoints(dt); ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just dont write `map.panTo()` after creating the marker, you ill need to use the click event of the marker inside which you should be writing the `panTo()`.

After your foreach loop, write:

```
function myMark(rmarker)
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(rmarker,'click',function(){
      map.panTo(rmarker.getPosition());
    });
}
```

Call the above function in your foreach loop at the end:

```
var marker" + i.ToString() + @" = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + Latitude + ", " + Longitude + @"),
                    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
                    map: map
                });";
                i++;
 myMark(marker" + i.ToString() + @"); 
}
```

The above will help you out with your issue.

**UPDATE:** Here is a working demo that shows your functionality:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cRdyd/1/)

See the coding pattern and you should be good to correct your mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to reply. umm.. `After your foreach loop, write:` wouldn't that be `before foreach loop` ?

Comment: I added this: `@"function myMark(rmarker)
        {
            google.maps.event.addListener(rmarker,'click',function(){
             map.panTo(rmarker.getPosition());
             });
          }";` (notice the @" and "; to end javascript code) But I get an error saying: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: Also, at the time of calling `myMark()` I get an error saying `marker` does not exist in the current context.  And if I write as above in your code `myMark(marker" + i.ToString() + @"); ` then I get an error saying `) expected` :|

Comment: No you first create the marker and then call `myMark()` so that each marker gets assigned with a `listener`.

Comment: No idea why the `@` and `;` that you have used. I already had the doubt about the syntaxes you used for creating the markers. The `var marker" + i.ToString() + @"` syntax doesn't look fine. You can write `var marker=..` It isn't required for them to have unique names.

Comment: please see the line: ` Locations += Environment.NewLine + @"` we have already started with -> @" after c# code. Also, `No you first create the marker and then call myMark() so that each marker gets assigned with a listener.` that does mean that the func. definition should come first i.e. above the foreach loop. Correct? (srry am newbie to c# + javascript mix):|

Comment: It doesn't matter if you write the function definition before or after the foreach loop. It will be called when you call it.

Comment: updating to `var marker=..` din't did any good :( The code gets compiled & was working fine **without** the `panTo` feature. I guess we are just missing something in the regular syntax thingy

Comment: I created a fiddle for you. See the Update in the answer. Check where you are going wrong.

Comment: Awesome! But isn't `panTo` feature zooms in to your marker on click..automatically?

Comment: `panTo()` is nothing but just the animated feature of `setCenter()`. There will be no zoom change.

Comment: LOL that' the zoom feature I am after.. :( and offcourse `setCenter()` too (your example works fine :) Thanks..) Any idea of how can I zoom in..with that animation if I click on a marker?

Comment: In `addListener function` include  `map.setZoom(15);` and you will be zoomed in. However, there is no way you can achieve the built in slow animation kind of effect with zoom in Google maps api3. So, that is it.

Comment: yeah.. I figured it out..well nvm :| Thanks for the help here.. :)